# Implement Image Indexing on a color palette based on indexing for text documents (Solr)

Tags: java, solr, solrj

I have added doubletype fields into the solr document. But it is being added as a **map of string fieldname, string[] fieldvalues** as the pre-built API supports only that. So does this mean I cannot perform a range query in solr?

I have defined the colorfield as a dynamic **TrieDoubleField** indexed and stored in the schema.xml. So I must be able to sort it depending on the colorfield?

Is this approach right?

And After indexing should I pre-process the query to extract *colorfield name* specifically or solr does it automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Ok let's try to simplify your problem, you want to search on a list of colors.
The colors might be transformed in text for example as blue and oceanblue.
store your colors with space as a list in a field.

Then search for a color like this :

```
q: *:*
fq: color:*blue*
will retrieve docs{ blue,blueocean}
```

The text can be stored like this 12:134:144  :)
Is that responding to your problem ?